# Chaining filter and map array by dictionary values in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

how can I use this type of chaining

```
let numbers = [20,17,35,4,12]
let evenSquares = numbers.filter{$0 % 2 == 0}.map{$0 * $0}
```

in such usecase

I have array of objects, I want to filter it by keys of external dictionary and then assign to those filtered objects value of dictionary where object id = dictionary key and then sort result object by dictionary value

here is code I have now:

```
let scoreDict: [String: Double]
var objects: [Object]
var filteredObjects = objects.filter { scoreDict.keys.contains.contains($0.id.uuidString.lowercased()) }
// .. and what next?
var scoresAssigned = filteredObjects.map { $0.score = scoreDict[$0.id.uuidString.lowercased()] } // This do not compile ""Cannot assign to property: '$0' is immutable"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Object` is a `struct`, based on the error message...

This just shows that higher-order functions shouldn't be used *everywhere*. `map` transforms each element in a sequence into something else. So instead of assigning `score`, you need to return a new `Object` with its `score` changed.

```
var scoresAssigned = filteredObjects.map { $0.withScore(scoreDict[$0.id.uuidString.lowercased()]) }
```

`withScore` will look something like:

```
func withScore(_ score: Int) -> Object {
    var copy = self
    copy.score = score
    return copy
}
```

***But***, if you just want to *assign* the score a new value, I recommend a simple for loop.

```
for i in 0..<filteredObjects.count {
    filteredObjects[i].score = scoreDict[$0.id.uuidString.lowercased()]
}
```

Also note that you only need to access the dictionary once. If it's nil, the key doesn't exist.

```
var filteredObjects = [Object]()
for i in 0..<objects.count {
    if let score = scoreDict[$0.id.uuidString.lowercased()] {
        objects[i].score = score
        filteredObjects.append(objects[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the return type in the `withScore(_:)` function